# Why does French have letter é and e?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, alphabet

I noticed there are `é` and `e` in the following sentence.

> représentent des sons (represent sounds)

Can I use `e` in place of `é`?

Comment: linked to [this](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21986/the-french-accents-marks-above-vowels).

Comment: so `du` and `dû`  are 2 different words?

Comment: @Tony yes, they are. "du" means "some" or "of the" depending on context, "dû" means "owed".

Comment: If your goal is to write in French, then no.

Comment: "Can I use e in place of é?" I am really curious, what could make you consider that you might?

Comment: No, the é and e in French are not pronounced the same way. They are two different sounds!!!

Comment: French also has e with an accent grave.  Take `élève` for example -- it has all three e's.

Comment: I was thinking `"Can I use e in place of é?" ` because if `é` and `e` are different, then French has more than 26 letters. The French alphabet should be listed as "a, b, c, d, e ,é, f...." etc.

Comment: By that logic, doesn't English have more than 26 letters?  How about `cease` and `continue`?  But, in any case, letters are not the same as diacritics.

Comment: English has only 26 letters. It does not have `é`, `û`  etc.

Comment: @Tony Well, that's a matter of opinion. _Né(e)_ has an é, _naïve_ has an ï, _façade_ has a ç, _piña colada_ has an ñ, _ångström_ has both an å and an ö… All these are conventional English spellings of English words. Your mistake is in thinking that “if _é_ and _e_ are different, then French has more than 26 letters”—that’s not necessarily true. It’s up to the conventions of each individual language to decide whether diacritics make separate letters of the alphabet or not. In Scandiwegian, for instance, _å_ is a separate letter; _é_ is not. In French, diacritics never make separate letters.

Comment: Ha! `diacritics` (变音符号) is the key to understand this. thanks.
I guess in French scrabble word game, `é, û` etc. will not be used.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many accents in French, you can't decide to use them or not as it pleases you.

It's always here for a reason, and if you don't use it when needed, either the word doesn't mean anything, or it means something else. Most of the time they change the pronunciation, too.

For example, for many verbs, the past participle ends with *é*:

> to buy / I buy / I've bought = acheter / j'achète / j'ai acheté

As you can see, *achète* and *acheté* don't have the same use (and don't pronounce the same way).

Some examples to show you accents are VERY common:

- *une forêt* = *a forest*
- *une mère, un père, un frère* = *a mother, a father, a brother*
- *un pré* = *a field*
- *Noël* = *Christmas*
- *s'il te plaît* = *please*
- *cocaïne* = *cocaine*
- *sûr* = *sure* / *safe* **BUT** *sur* = *on* / *over*
- *à* = *to* / *in* **BUT** (*il*) *a* = (*he*) *has*
- *un hôpital* = *a hospital*
- *où* = *where* **BUT** *ou* = *or*

For many words, you have to learn them as they are, the pronunciation often helps, and there are rules too.

Bonus: *créée* (= *created*, feminine past participle of the verb *créer* = *to create*).

Comment: To make a long explanation short, it's basically a new letter in our alphabet. E is pronounced 'euh', É is more like 'eh' and È is more like 'esh'. They cannot be replaced by each other. E =/= É =/= È =/=

Comment: It might be worth noting that since 1990 many "î" and "û" can be replaced by "i" and "u", with a few (almost) simple rules rules telling when the accent can be omitted.

Comment: Yeah the circ is being more and more obmitted overtime. Those f-ers are just there to trip you up.

Comment: Non constructive comments have been removed. Please remember that comments are not meant for extended discussion: we have [a chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=french.stackexchange.com) for that.

Comment: You can link the ^ to a lingering s in most cases. e.g. hôpital vs ho**s**pital

Comment: How can créée exist? In the compound past, créer is conjugated with avoir, therefore agreement of the past participle is not needed. I understand créé, but how is it possible to use créée?

Comment: *Elle est créée* = *she/it (f.) is created*.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Furthermore there is an agreement with *avoir* if the *COD* is before the verb: *"La mélodie qu'il a créée est magnifique."*

Answer (score 12):

This is an accent called acute. é is therefore called "e acute". The prononciation is different from e and cannot be dropped in **any case** unless an alternative spelling exists (like clef and clé).

The answer to your question on the presence of `é` is simply that this is how the word should be spelled.

Comment: Sorry, not e acute. An e with an acute accent. Otherwise, this is the only correct answer here.

Comment: @Lambie in English, it is often simply called e-acute.

Answer (score 5):

This character is a "e accent aigu", you pronounce it like the "e" in "heya". Writing the words with a simple "e" instead is a mistake. You can do that only when:

- The "é" is a capital letter (though you could use the capital "É", a simple "E" is easier to write). In this case, be aware of the possible ambiguities.
- You are writing something using the ASCII format ("é" isn't part of ASCII so you don't have a choice)

Some words have very different meanings if you forget the accent: for example "tombé" means "fallen" whereas "tombe" means "grave"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47627/discussion-on-answer-by-anne-aunyme-why-does-french-have-letter-e-and-e).

Answer (score 2):

Not seeing the "real" reason: these accents replace the letter s - "école" - very similar to "school" in English, for example. Or "forêt" (as above) is similar to "forest" - French evolved from Latin, after all, and in that evolution the writing changed a bit, and the s became the accent mark. It helps the reader to figure out pronunciation as well, because those silent s impact the way the word is pronounced (roughly). So basically, it's part of the proper/correct spelling of these words. And that means they're not the same letter, really. They're more like digraphs. French considers them to be, but Spanish, for example, considers n and nn to be different letters.

Comment: Sometimes, but not always. For example, there was no "s" in past participles ending in "é".

Answer (score 2):

The bare letter «e» is pronounced /ǝ/ (or dropped) unless there's something about its context to make it /e/ (like «é»; as in *cachet*) or /ɛ/ (like «è»; as in *bel*) or /ɑ̃/ (as in *content*) or /ɛ̃/ (as in *bien*).  Any diacritic makes it a full vowel, never a schwa.

Comment: Except maybe in the word *aiguë*.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the e accent aigu (é) is to distinguish the phoneme /e/ from the phoneme /ə/. In the example phrase, *représentent* is thus pronounced /ʁǝpʁezɑ̃/. This is no different in principle from how *represent* is pronounced as /rɛprɪzɛnt/ in English.

NB The circumflex, such as in *forêt*, is used to indicate an *s* that used to be pronounced. I chose this example because the English word fore*s*t makes this easy to see. In principle you could therefore leave out the circumflexes for pronunciation purposes, but many are still kept to prevent homonymy in writing. That being said, I'd strongly advise against leaving out or replacing any accents in practice.

Comment: Aren't there some words in which dropping the circumflex could change /ɛ/ (like «è») to /ǝ/?

Comment: In that case "dropping the circumflex" would mean replacing it with a grave accent. ;)

Comment: I almost wrote that the circumflex is equivalent to the grave, but it's content-dependent; I don't think _forèt_, for example, could exist in the standard language.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Both *foret* (as in drill bit) and *forêt* are pronounced the same as *forèt* would be, so it seems to me that it already exists quite convincingly.

Comment: Is there any word containing the letter ‹è› before either a final consonant (letter) or a single consonant followed by a vowel?

Comment: (Argh, where I wrote “content-dependent” of course I meant “context-dependent”.)

Comment: I have no idea; is there a French electronic dictionary that allows for regular expression search? See the English-language [Regex Dictionary](http://visca.com/regexdict/) as an example of what I mean. But I'd say that writing *forèt* is really no different than writing *foret* when you mean forêt. I suppose you could argue it's even more wrong

Comment: For the second part of my last question, yes: verb forms like _mène_.

Comment: But that *e* is not a vowel. It's /mɛn/. :-)